# i got this exception java.io.IOException: Expected chunk of type 0x11c0200, read 0x1200200

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

i got this Exception

```
  R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
    R java.io.IOException: Expected chunk of type 0x11c0200, read 0x1200200.
    R   at com.ibm.puremeap.util.android.ReadUtil.readCheckType(ReadUtil.java:32)
    R   at com.ibm.puremeap.util.android.AndroidResourceParser.readPackage(AndroidResourceParser.java:80)
    R   at com.ibm.puremeap.util.android.AndroidResourceParser.read(AndroidResourceParser.java:62)
    R   at com.ibm.puremeap.util.android.AndroidAPKResolver.resolve(AndroidAPKResolver.java:138)
    R   at com.ibm.puremeap.util.android.AAPT.getMetadata(AAPT.java:362)
    R   at com.ibm.puremeap.services.UploadService.fileUploaded(UploadService.java:153)
    R   at com.ibm.puremeap.services.UploadService.__fileUploadedJSON__(UploadService.java:106)
    R   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    R   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    R   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    R   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    R   at
```

org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)

when am trying to upload APK to Worklight application center i ran the application using eclipse i read the documentation regard AAPT but i don't understand which path should use since i searched for the paths on my machine they are note exist

Comment: The log is inconclusive. What is that log? Please share more of it.

Comment: Also mention your worklight/mfp version, your android version, and any other detail about your environment that you did not mention.....

Comment: I am Building  Application using Maximo Anywhere(Mobile First)  which use Worklight 6.1.0 this over websphere Server  android version 19 
*This exception Log  from Websphere when i am trying to uplaod apk using Worklight Console Web or usning Build Tools

Comment: Contact maximo support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was in setting AAPT path in Websphere server when I had to chose the full path till the AAPT.exe file 
\tools\android-sdk*bin.windows-x86* 
*Depending in your platform

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to upload an APK that was built for Android 5.x, and are encountering the problem described by [APAR PI30639](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI30639).  This is an issue in the fallback code that the Application Center uses when the Android AAPT tool is not present or is not usable.  It will not occur if you have one of the "android.aapt" or "android.aapt.dir" JNDI names defined to point to a working version of the AAPT tool - there is a documentation link in the APAR page that describes how to do this, and where you should be able to find the AAPT tool on your system.

There is a fix for this problem in the latest Worklight 6.1.0.2 iFix, which is available on IBM Fix Central.  If you aren't using the AAPT tool, then you'll need this fix.

If you do use the AAPT tool, and your Worklight Server is on a 64-bit Linux system, you will also need to [install some 32-bit shared libraries](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/183802/errors-are-logged-on-my-64-bit-linux-server-indica.html) so that the AAPT tool can run.

Comment: Thanks A lot this was very helpful the path should be full till \tools\android-sdk\bin.windows-x86